# How to load images from JSON into UIImageView using SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I'm trying to display images from a JSON url in an UIImageView, similar to Tinder, using SDWebImage. Every tutorial I've come across only deal with downloading either single image urls (@"suchandsuch.png"), or displaying the images inside of tableviews (which I do not want to do).

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

My sample code: ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager GET:@"http://www.suchandsuch.com/api/sites" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.posts = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
        self.post = self.posts[@"sites"];
       NSLog(@"JSON: %@", self.post);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];


    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.suchandsuch.com/api/sites"]];


    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:data
                                options:kNilOptions
                                error:&error];

    NSString *logoString = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"logoURL"];

    NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logoString];
    [self.myImage setImageWithURL:logoURL];


    }
```

Comment: A URL is a URL.  The fact that it came from a JSON string is irrelevant.

Comment: (Is the problem that you don't know how to parse JSON, or that you don't know how to convince SDWebImage to serve up your images?)

Comment: @HotLicks I've parsed the JSON already, I'm just having trouble having SDWebImage display the images, using the photos parameter from JSON, in the UIImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you have the SDWebImage files added to your project already and that you know how to parse the JSON, here's all you need to do. Add this line to the top of your view controller class -

```
#import "UIImageView+Webcache.h
```

After you've parsed and retrieved the object contains the imageUrl that you need, for example the dictionary (dict) extracted from the JSON

Example

```
    NSString *jsonImageUrlString = [dict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonImageUrlString];

    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey:imageURL fromDisk:YES];

    [self.profileImageView setImageWithURL:imageURL];
```

I hope this helps

**EDIT**
***SDWebImage files that you should already have in your project***

[image]

Comment: Can you check you have the the above SDWebImage files within your project, which would have been in the folder when you added them in.

Comment: sorry, please check again, I put in wrong screenshot there. Correct one in now

Comment: Yeah, I have the SDWebImage folder in my project. And I imported the UIImageView+Webcache.h class in my ViewController.m

Comment: I've added a line to the code, which will clear the cache before it sets the image.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! I just tried again and it worked!! :) You're the best!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a JSON structure which has a dictionary of imageUrl's . You need to convert the JSON to an NSObject through this snippet of code.

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary*jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData    options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString *imageUrl = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"imageURLKEY"];

[yourImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyTempImage.png"]];
```