# SDWebImage not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I'm trying use SDWebImage for downloading image from a web. But it's not working. How can I fix it?

DetailView.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:_downloadedimage]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f), .size=_img.size};  // I think what error here
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = _img.size; // and here?
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not working? Explain in detail what are you expecting and what you got?

Comment: This is a similar question about SWWebImage, if you look at that answer it may help    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984949/how-to-load-images-from-json-into-uiimageview-using-sdwebimage

Comment: ImageView always empty.

Comment: Have you verified that `self.imageView` is not `nil`?

Comment: I wrote in code `if (_imageView.image==nil) {AlertView}`, and I get ImageView always nil.

Comment: Fix that problem and the image will start working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you not initialized imageview. Try to do it before.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.imageView == nil)
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:_downloadedimage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly Import the lib.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

and then add this line

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"urlString" placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];
```

Make sure you using a valid url that contain some image and the image you are assigning to your placeholder should be there aswell.

Comment: the answer marked as right is the same so why downvoted.